# How to detect which code is using locations in the background in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, background, location

Our app for navigation: minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30. We have no services in the background, we remove our updatelistener in onPause() and we request only location permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, so we should never be even able to use a location in the background. So far the theory. In the App COntent section we indicated we indeed don't use locations in the background and there the questionnaire does not continue, as the interaction flow ended there successfully.

But Google just removed our app from the Play store as it believes it is violating the policy about using the device location in the background. The Developer Permission Declaration in de Play store has a Sensitive App Rights section mentioning "Location rights: not used in the background".

In interaction with Google - very cumbersome - we got this after weeks:
We found that your app is not compliant with the Location Permissions policy, or we were unable to review and verify your in-app experience for compliance with this policy.

If you have determined that your app does not require location in the background, complete the following steps to remove background usage and reach compliance:

For any APK targeting Android 10 or newer (SDK level 29 or higher):
Remove the  ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission from your app APK or app bundle
[If minimum SDK level is 28 or lower] If you’re using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only (learn more)

You should no longer see the Location declaration listed under App Content
For any APK targeting Android 9 or older (SDK level 28 or lower):
If you’re already using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only (learn more)
In your console declaration, select “No” to the question “Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 or older?”

We believe we did exactly that. ANy interaction over email takes days and always goes into a loop, back to square one.

Our questions:

1. Could it be that the MapBox library 6.6.0 uses locations in the background? We don't call their code to initialize any fetching of locations, as we update the map position ourselves.
2. Is there any way of determining where the violation - if at all - takes place?
3. Any other improvements that may help?